# Why won't this css work in IE 8?

Tags: css

The padding, margin etc. all work, but the image won't display in IE 8, any idea why?

CSS

```
.arrow {
background:url(images/arrow.png) center left no-repeat;
padding-left:23px;
padding-right:10px;
border-right:0px solid #e6e6e6;
margin-right:10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="arrow">
<h3><b>Headline</b></h3>
</div>
```

`h3` CSS

```
h3{
font-size:14px;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Comment: @steveax: Here you go, enjoy: http://jsfiddle.net/RTe4G/

Comment: Maybe use quotes `url('images/arrow.png')`

Comment: This so temps the answer of IE sucks.

Comment: Works fine for me on IE9 in IE8 mode, not sure why it wouldn't. Can you provide a screen shot? *Are you **100% sure** there's no other CSS or HTML involved?* Did you actually confirm it works in another browser?

Comment: Is the `<h3>` inside floated or absolute positioned? If so, the div will have no dimensions, and you'll have to set them manually.

Comment: Please post the CSS for the h3 heading.

Comment: Looks like it's not the `h3`... :(. But you could try setting width and height for `.arrow` anyway, just as a test.

Comment: @Paul: Please upload the image file and link it so we can test or try with `background-color`, or post a live demo that we can actually see this error on. There is nothing here at all that suggests the background image wouldn't work.

Comment: @Xander - it's on an intranet. No outside access is allowed.

Comment: Can you post your HTML from your DOCTYPE through the HEAD tag?  I wonder if you have a BASE tag set set in your HTML that could be causing a problem in IE?  I seem to recall that happening to me once.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](http://www.siteduzero.com/forum-83-500440-p1-ie8-li-background-image.html) (in french), try with a space before url

```
background: url(images/arrow.png) center left no-repeat;
```

I have not personally tested, but it worked for this user

Comment: Spaces after the colon are meaningless, it's just formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Try surrounding the url with single quotation marks (or whatever they're called).

```
background:url('images/arrow.png') center left no-repeat;
```

Comment: The only other thing I could think of is the file not existing at that location. See if images/arrow.png is the right path.

Comment: @StoneRanger - It's there. Checked twice. It works in FF and Chrome just fine

Comment: One last shot: change background to background-image
background-image:url('images/arrow.png') center left no-repeat;

Answer (score 2):

in case my mobile phone displays it correctly, put the background shorthand on a single line, linebreaks confuse ie.

Comment: Examine the computed styles and look for possible errors/overrides.

Comment: Additionally switch center and left, the horizontal declaration comes first in the shorthand. If that wont help, break up the shorthand into its single declarations.